# Retrieve text iteration using loops in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following code to retrieve all the image links on a webpage

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_txt(soup, key):
    key_tag = soup.find('span', text=re.compile(key)).parent
    return key_tag.find_all('span')[1].text

urldes = "https://www.johnpyeauctions.co.uk/lot_list.asp?saleid=4709&siteid=1"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(urldes, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

image_links = [x['data-img'] for x in soup.find_all('a', rel='popover')]
for link in image_links:
    print(link)
```

I would like to apply the same principle in order to retrieve the text description that goes with each image:

```
soup.find_all(width='41%')
for text in soup.find_all('h5'):
    print(text)
```

This code retrieves all the `<h5>` tags BUT not the specific tag with the parent `(width='41%')`.

I have tried to apply the same loop as above for the image links:

```
image_text = [x['h5'] for x in soup.find_all(width='41%')]
for text in image_text:
    print(text)
```

But I get the following error:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\jpye_v2.py", line 41, in <module>
    image_text = [x['h5'] for x in soup.find_all(width='41%')]
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\jpye_v2.py", line 41, in <listcomp>
    image_text = [x['h5'] for x in soup.find_all(width='41%')]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3.6.egg\bs4\element.py", line 1011, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'h5'`
```

What I don't understand is why the tag `h5` gives an error where the tag `a` does not or can I not use the same loop to index the text iterations in the same way as the image links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, simply writing this line `soup.find_all(width='41%')`, doesn't do anything. The `find_all()` method **returns a list** of all the matching tags. So, you'll have to store that in a variable first, and then iterate over it.

For your second code, `tag['attribute']` is used to get the **value of the `attribute`** for the `tag`. So, using `x['h5']` will raise a `KeyError` since `h5` is not a attribute, but a tag.

Finally, to get the text that you want, you can use this:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('td', width='41%'):
    image_text = tag.find('h5').text
    print(image_text)
```

Or, to show how the `find_all()` method works, you can check this:

```
tags = soup.find_all('td', width='41%')
for tag in tags:
    image_text = tag.find('h5').text
    print(image_text)
```

Partial Output:

```
GUESS C0001G1 GENTS ROSE GOLD TONE AND BLUE BRUSH POLISHED SMART WATCH WITH VOICE COMMAND.  FITTED WITH A BLUE SMOOTH SILICONE STRAP.BOXED AND PAPERS. RRP £259.00
GUESS I14503L1 LADIES SPORT WATCH WITH POLISHED SILVER COLOUR CASE WITH CRYSTALS, SILVER DIAL AND POLISHED SILVER COLOUR BRACELET. RRP £159
GUESS W0111L2 LADIES WATCH. POLISHED GOLD COLOUR CASE WITH CRYSTALS AND GOLD COLOUR MULTI-FUNCTION DIAL AND BRACELET. RRP £189
GUESS W0072L3 LADIES TREND WATCH. POLISHED ROSE GOLD CASE WITH CRYSTALS AND ROSE GOLD DIAL. POLISHED ROSE GOLD MULTI-CHAIN BRACELET WITH ADJUSTING G-LINK. RRP £159
GUESS W0330L2 LADIES SPORT WATCH. POLISHED ROSE GOLD COLOUR CASE WITH ROSE GOLD COLOUR CHRONO LOOK MULTI FUNCTION DIAL AND ROSE GOLD COLOUR BRACELET. RRP £169
GUESS W13573L1 LADIES SPORT WATCH. POLISHED GOLD COLOURED CASE WITH CRYSTAL AND WHITE MULTI FUNCTION DAIL AND POLISHED GOLD COLOURED BRACELET. RRP £169
GUESS W0674G6 MENS WATCH. ROSE GOLD CASE WITH BLACK TRIM AND SUN/ BLACK MULTI FUNCTION DIAL AND BLACK CROCODILE STYLE LEATHER BRACELET. RRP £169
GUESS W0564L1 LADIES SPORT WATCH. ROSE GOLD COLOUR CASING WITH BLUE TRIM AND CRYSTALS, WHITE MULTI FUNCTION DIAL WITH SMOOTH SILICONE STRAP. RRP £149
GUESS W0425L3 LADIES SPORT WATCH. POLISHED ROSE GOLD/ ANIMAL PRINT CASE AND SUN ROSE GOLD AND ANIMAL DAIL WITH POLISHES ROSE GOLD AND ANIMAL PRINT BRACELET. RRP £189
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`width=41%` is an attribute. This will get you closer to what you want:

```
for text in soup.find_all('td', {'width': '41%'}):
    print(text)
```